# Does Uncle Ben exist in the MCU?

Tags: character, marvel-cinematic-universe, spider-man-homecoming, spider-man-far-from-home

Uncle Ben, the man who raised Peter from birth with his wife May, and who taught Peter the lesson that inspires him to be a hero, who is the base for the iconic phrase "with great power, comes great responsibility" hasn't been seen in the MCU. Tom Holland's Spider Man has been in five movies so far. We've seen Aunt May and Tony Stark works as a father/mentor figure for him. As far as I remember, there has been no indication about Uncle Ben so far.

So that makes me wonder... Does Uncle Ben exist in the MCU? If so, in what condition? Is he dead as usual or alive somehow or something completely different than above two?

Answer (score 12):

Yes (kind of) as per director, from [screencrush](https://screencrush.com/does-mcu-spider-man-have-an-uncle-ben/)

> Did Tom Holland’s Peter Parker have an Uncle Ben? This time, Watts gave me a much more concrete, much more detailed answer.
>
> > “Yes. Definitely. Did you notice his initials on Peter’s suitcase?”

[image]

He continued;

> “Yes, Uncle Ben did exist in the MCU,” he replied “Yeah. I mean, we don’t know,” and then he took a long pause before adding “We never specifically say anything about him. So whether or not he’s around or not.”

But at-least his suitcase exists for sure in MCU. But his name was Benjamin "Ben" Parker in comics without F.

Comment: The linked article has this after the quoted line,  *...When I noted that he is now willing to say “Yes, Uncle Ben did exist in the MCU,” he replied “Yeah. I mean, we don’t know,” and then he took a long pause before adding “We never specifically say anything about him. So whether or not he’s around or not.”* Man..., I'm confused :/

Comment: @Vishwa I was editing answer only

Comment: Apart from Watts deliberately saying about some initials in Peter's suitcase, it could've mean anything. could've been some antique suitcase of someone peter admired, could be a superhero, or even it could be some used suitcase he bought for cheap price.. how can we be so sure it's Uncle Ben's?

Comment: @Vishwa because trust the director

Comment: Upon reading his comments, I'm not sure even director trusts the director

Comment: @Vishwa but this what we have till sequels

Comment: Uncle Ben's middle name was Franklin (as per the wikipedia page on the character), hence the B.F.P.

Comment: @GeoffAtkins So he's Benjamin Franklin.. a.k.a Founding Father of the United States eh? ;)  in this case seems like, Founding Father of Spider Man

Comment: My assumption is he's already dead. Just like in the other SM film series/TV series.

Comment: In homecoming, when Ned finds out Peter says he can;t tell May when asked why he replies "come on man... after everything she's been through" so this does suggest that something very bad has happened in her past, that mixed with the suitcase suggest there was an uncle ben, but he had already died by the time of homecoming